# Storing GridViewRow Object between Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the following code to highlight a row the user clicks on in gridview (and unhighlights previously selected row):

```
    protected void PartListRowClicked(object sender, GridViewRowClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        pnewrow = (GridViewRow)PartList.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex];
        pnewrow.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        pnewrow.ForeColor = Color.White;
        if (poldrow != null)
        {
            poldrow.BackColor = Color.Empty;
            poldrow.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        poldrow = pnewrow;
    }
```

However, the poldrow object is always reset to null after a postback (clicking causes a postback). Is there a way to save the row index between postbacks? Or alternatively, is there a better way to implement this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: You can store the data in the ViewState of the page: ViewState["SomeKey"] = poldrow and access later.

Comment: I would propose using a **clientSide** script (_Jquery_) to change the style of a row!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the value in `ViewState` or `Session`:

```
public int CurrentRowIndex
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["rowindex"] != null ?
               int.Parse(ViewState["rowindex"]) :
               0;
    }

    set
    {
        ViewState["rowindex"] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible to *store the oldRow(index) at the server.* For example you may use a **ViewState** or a **Session var**. But imo **it's a long way to the server and back** *only to change the color/style of a row*. So I would propose to **use JQuery to change the style of a row**, unless you have to note a rowClicked event on the server?!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oldRow = null;
    var newRow = null;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // gvProducts is my gridView
        $("#gvProducts tr:gt(0)").click(function () {
            oldRow = newRow;
            newRow = $(this);

            newRow.css("background-color", "blue");
            newRow.css("color", "white");

            if (oldRow != null) {
                oldRow.css("background-color", "transparent");
                oldRow.css("color", "black");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Using this script you **stay on the client** and your clients won't have to make a postback to the server just for setting a style!

Comment: This is a good idea. Unfortunately when I click on a row, I also need to update some textboxes on the page with the values in the gridviewrow which is pulled from a sql database so I think I need to have viewstates.

Comment: As this is a possibility I (!) would rather try to send an [_ajax request_](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) within the click function. So you don't habe to update the complete page, can use this clientSideScript AND do some async postback.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply save the index into a session or viewstate or cookie ! and after the postback use that value to retrieve what ever you want !

set :

```
Session["rowindex"]="the index";
```

get :

```
string index=Session["rowindex"].ToString();
```